# Spanish number tickformatting ticks with plotly

Tags: python, plotly, number-formatting

I need to change the "," to a "." in both axes. This should be an easy and reproducible example:

```
import plotly.express as px
import pandas as pd


df = pd.DataFrame(
{"pop" : [1000000, 1500000, 2000000, 2500000, 4000000, 4500000],
"exports" : [26000000, 30000000, 35000000, 40000000, 45000000, 90000000],
"year" : [2018, 2018, 2019, 2019, 2020, 2020],
"prov": ['a', 'b', 'a', 'b', 'a', 'b']})
df

fig = px.scatter(
    df, x="pop",
    y="exports", animation_frame="year",
    animation_group="prov",
    size = "pop",
    hover_name="prov",
    log_x=True, size_max=50,
    range_x=[900000,4600000],
    range_y=[25000000,100000000],
    title='Exports per province and popultion <br><sup>Bubble size depends on population',
    template="simple_white"
    )
fig.update_traces(textposition='top center')

fig.update_layout(
    font = dict(
        family="helvetica neueltstd",
        size = 18
        )
    )
    
fig.update_yaxes(tickformat = ",")
fig.update_xaxes(tickformat = ",")
fig
```

Then, I export it to html.

```
fig.write_html("stack.html")
```

The last part: "tickformat" allows me to set a "," separator, but I'm looking towards a "." separator.
This is the result:

[image]

Help is much appreciated!

Comment: There's no thousands separator anywhere in that image. Could you please modify your example code so that it is complete and runnable --including sample data-- so that one could attempt to reproduce it locally.

Comment: I'm sorry, thanks for the comment! I think it should do the trick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the end of your code before you export your figure, you can add the following line (the documentation for separators is [here](https://plotly.com/python-api-reference/generated/plotly.graph_objects.Layout.html)):

```
## sets decimal and thousands: default in english locales is ".,"
fig.update_layout(separators=",.")
```

Then you get decimal points as separators.

[image]

Comment: It worked! Thank you very much, it took me hours.

Comment: No problem, @Keynesisnotdead!